# In complete graph, how can I prove ${n\choose 2} = {k\choose 2} + k(n-k) + {n-k\choose 2}$ for $0 \le k \le n$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm studying graphs in algorithm and complexity, but I'm not very good at math. How can I prove that
${n\choose 2} = {k\choose 2} + k(n-k) + {n-k\choose 2}$ for $0 \le k \le n$?

Comment: Do you understand why a complete graph with $m$ vertices has ${m\choose 2}$ edges? also, I think you mean $k(n-k)$ in that middle term, no?

Comment: yes i know that a complete graph with m vertices has C(m, 2) but, I don't know that how can prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider a complete graph on $n$ vertices and partition its vertex set in two subsets, one with $k$ and one with $n-k$ elements. How many edges does the graph have in total? How many are there within each of the two subsets? Can you finish off the argument?

Comment: Okay. I will try it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be partitioned into two sets $A$ and $B$, where $A=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and $B = \{k+1,\ldots,n\}$.  In how many ways can we choose two elements from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$?  There are three possibilities: both elements are from $A$ (the two elements can be chosen in ${k \choose 2}$ ways), both elements are from $B$, or one element is from $A$ and the other element is from $B$.